# Jquery Tabs auto scroll/rotate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

My tabs work perfectly, but every time i try to add a rotate they break.    Where should i be lookign to add this in, i've been looking at tutorials for the last few horus and can't seem to figure it out ;/ any pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/GFphT/62/

Answer (score 0):

```
//array to store IDs of our tabs
var tabs = [];
//index for array
var ind = 0;
//store setInterval reference
var inter;

//change tab and highlight current tab title
function change(stringref){
    //hide the other tabs
    jQuery('.tab:not(#' + stringref + ')').hide();
    //show proper tab, catch IE6 bug
    if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3) == "6.0")
        jQuery('.tab#' + stringref).show();
    else 
        jQuery('.tab#' + stringref).fadeIn();
    //clear highlight from previous tab title
    jQuery('.htabs a:not(#' + stringref + 't)').removeClass('active');
    //highlight currenttab title
    jQuery('.htabs a[href=#' + stringref + ']').addClass('active');
}
function next(){
    //call change to display next tab
    change(tabs[ind++]);
    //if it's the last tab, clear the index
    if(ind >= tabs.length)
        ind = 0;
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //store all tabs in array
    jQuery(".tab").map(function(){
        tabs[ind++] = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    })
    //set index to next element to fade
    ind = 1;
    //initialize tabs, display the current tab
    jQuery(".tab:not(:first)").hide();
    jQuery(".tab:first").show();
    //highlight the current tab title
    jQuery('#' + tabs[0] + 't').addClass('active');
    //handler for clicking on tabs
    jQuery(".htabs a").click(function(){

        //if tab is clicked, stop rotating 
        clearInterval(inter);
        //store reference to clicked tab
        stringref = jQuery(this).attr("href").split('#')[1];
        //display referenced tab
        change(stringref);
        return false;
    });
    //start rotating tabs
    inter = setInterval("next()", 7500);
});
```